# Convert a PDA with transition for a state to itself to another PDA

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, pushdown-automata

Suppose we have PDA (same for DFA and Turing) that has a transition from a state to itself. Can we convert this PDA to another one without any transition like this?

EDIT (My thoughts):
I guess we can do it. for example in a PDA [image]
we might be able to do this(?)

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: @Steven I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the $\epsilon$'s with $a$'s then what you did is a possible solution (that is, cloning the transition from $q_0$ to itself into two identical transitions: $q_0\rightarrow q_1$ and $q_1\rightarrow q_0)$. **however**, notice that any transition *from* $q_0$ must also be duplicated to be a transition from $q_1$. In addition, don't forget to make the duplicated state an accepting state if the original was an accepting state

So, doing this while cloning all transitions and other properties, will ensure that the DFA/PDA/TM will be equivalent.

Notice that in the special case of TM the accepting state will never be duplicated, since it doesn't have any transitions at all.

Comment: If I exchange ϵ 's with a's then I must read 2 "a" from input and it'll not be the same output

Comment: Hence you need to duplicate all transitions that were from $q_0$ to also be in $q_1$.